# Call two models dependent on each other in one controller for a view

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to Rails so I am going to try and explain this the best I can.

I have three models: artist, fest, and festival_artist

artist contains only an ID and an artist_name
fest contains only an ID and a festival_name
festival_artist contains an ID, a artist_id, and a festival_id

I created Fest using a scaffold so that is where my controller and show.html.erb is.

Below are my models:

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :festival_artist
end

class Fest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :festival_artist
end

class FestivalArtist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artists
  has_many :fests
end
```

In my fests_controller.rb I have:

```
def show
  @festival_artists = FestivalArtist.where(festival_id: @fest.id) 
end
```

I tried to add:

```
def show
  @festival_artists = FestivalArtist.where(festival_id: @fest.id) 
  @artists = Artist.where(id: @festival_artists.artist_id)
end
```

However, that throws an undefined method artist_id for # error.

The goal is to display the Artist's name in the Fest's show.html.erb page for the festival that that artist belongs to.

In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT A.artist_name
FROM festival_artists AS FA
INNER JOIN artists AS A
ON FA.artist_id = A.id
```

Any suggestions? Even telling me what to Google would help out because I'm not sure my terminology is correct.

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess your models structure is not 100% correct. Try to check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for details.

There are to ways to handle your associations in Rails:

1. HABTM (has and belongs to many), as noticed in @grizzthedj answer.
2. has_many :through association

In this case your code will look like

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :festival_artists
  has_many :fests, through: :festival_artists
end

class Fest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :festival_artists
  has_many :artists, through: :festival_artists
end

class FestivalArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artists
  belongs_to :fests
end
```

So you can access artists in the controller

```
def show
  @festival_artists = @fest.artists
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I had to change the FestivalArtist class to make those singular but after that it worked. I'll read up more on that article.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you need the FestivalArtist model. If you use "has_and_belongs_to_many" in Artist and Fest models, this will implement the many-to-many relation that you are looking for.

```
# fest.rb
class Fest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :artists
end

# artist.rb
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :fests
end
```

Comment: But if the artist model doesn't have a festival_id and the fest model doesn't have an artist_id, how would they be connected?

Comment: Right. Forgot about that. Thanks!